# Cookies not being set in Android WebView with PHP

Tags: php, android, cookies, webview

I have an app which calls a PHP website using WebView. Whenever someone logs in, I set cookies using the following PHP code:

```
setcookie('id', $row['id'], time() + $time, "/");
setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + $time, "/");
```

After this, in the app, I've written the following lines for cookie management:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebview, true);
} else {
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
}
```

Now I've tried all the solutions given on stack overflow and none of them are working. Please help!

Comment: Before setcookie() make sure you don't output anything or cookie setting will fail.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Oh okay let me see..one sec!

Comment: @KarloKokkak I checked it..there are no output statements before set cookie()

Comment: How about before your first `<?php` ??

Comment: @KarloKokkak yup..none at all..its a backend file which is being called through an Ajax call in my JS..so no outputs in that file

Comment: If you open the website in a regular web browser are the cookies set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167936/discussion-between-karlo-kokkak-and-siddharth-umachandar).

Comment: @KarloKokkak I just tried it on my laptop..I set the cookies then closed the browser and on opening it back up, the id cookie was set but the username one wasn't! What's the problem here?